# Finding The Rate at Which a Single Machine Works

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An engineer can finish a job in $3$ days with his present number of machines. However with $3$ more of these machines the job could be done in 2 days. The machines all work at the same rate. How could I calculate the number of days it would take a single machine to complete the entire job?

(The answer is supposed to be $18$ days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model the problem as:

$\displaystyle D = \frac kN$

where $D$ is the number of days it takes to finish a job, $N$ is the number of machines available and $k$ is a constant - in fact it is this constant you are required to find. This is a simple inverse relationship; the more machines, the quicker the job gets done in a proportional fashion.

Set up two equations:

$\displaystyle 3 = \frac k{N_0}$, where $N_0$ is the initial number of machines

and $\displaystyle 2 = \frac k{N_0 + 3}$

Solve them simultaneously and you'll get $\displaystyle k = 18$, which is the number of days a single machine would take.